# AEM arch type to generate latest angular

Tags: angular, aem-6

Trying to create a new Angular AEM Project which uses latest angular versions 14+.

But this archtype always generating an angular with 9.
**using archetypeVersion:47**

What needs to be changed to generate with latest angular

```
 mvn -B org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.1:generate \
 -D archetypeGroupId=com.adobe.aem \
 -D archetypeArtifactId=aem-project-archetype \
 -D archetypeVersion=47 \
 -D appTitle="WKND SPA Angular" \
 -D appId="wknd-spa-angular" \
 -D artifactId="aem-guides-wknd-spa.angular" \
 -D groupId="com.adobe.aem.guides.wkndspa.angular" \
 -D frontendModule="angular" \
 -D aemVersion="cloud"
```